# Three variables as heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I want to plot my data as a heatmap which has the following structure:

`X = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
Y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Z = [0.2, 0.33, 0.1, 0.25, 0.0, 0.9, 0.75, 0.88, 0.44, 0.95]`

The x and y-axis shall be represented by X and Y, while the 'heat' is represented by the values of Z.

E.g. at coordinate (x,y) = (1,2) the intensity shall be 0.33
How can this be achieved by using matplotlib? 
Looking at posts which relate to the keyword heatmap or even to those related to the term contour map, I could not transfer it to this problem yet.

Thank you in advance for any hints
Dan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hope your data is just an example because it will look funny (it's more a sequence of strips; the x-dimension is constant).

I would recommend the usage of [pandas (general data-analysis)](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and [seaborn (matplotlib-extensions)](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/) which makes it a bit nicer.

#### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
X = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
Y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Z = [0.2, 0.33, 0.1, 0.25, 0.0, 0.9, 0.75, 0.88, 0.44, 0.95]
data = pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'Y': Y, 'Z': Z})
data_pivoted = data.pivot("X", "Y", "Z")
ax = sns.heatmap(data_pivoted)
plt.show()
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Good answer <padding>