# How to plot data dependent on two variables in a discrete heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, graphing, imshow

I have 3 lists of data, `x`,`y`,`z` which I want to plot as a discrete `colourmap` type graph with the `x` and `y` being the coordinates of the `z` data point, and the z-value corresponding to a colour in the usual sense.

My data is of the form:

```py
x = [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]

y = [0.002, 0.0024, 0.0028, 0.0032, 0.0036, 0.002, 0.0024, 0.0028, 0.0032, 0.0036]

z = [1884.7, 1783.7, 2065.7, 1778.0, 2042.0, 2615.7, 2814.0, 2605.0, 1538.3, 1981.3]
```

I've tried using `imshow`/`matshow` by reshaping the `z` data into an `m` by `n` matrix, but the issue there is that the `x`/`y` axes only have values corresponding to the index of the z-matrix.  Ideally I'd like something like the image below, but with the numbers on the axes referring to my `x`/`y` data.

Thanks very much.

[image]

Comment: [Here's](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolor.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolor) what I think you are looking for.

Comment: this seems to be the simplest seaborn alternative. thanks very much.

Comment: take note of how the input needs to be formatted. it is not exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use seaborn instead of matplotlib for a heatmap. See the following question for a nice example: [Three variables as heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041865/three-variables-as-heatmap)

Comment: It appears the university system I'm using doesn't have seaborn available unfortunately.  Otherwise this would have been ideal.

Comment: I've since been able to install seaborn